# How to complete a sequence based on condition in R (example provided)?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse

I have a data frame dt and I want to fill hours from 0 to 23 with conditions as given below

1. For min of date1 ,hour1 should start from minimum of hour1 [ ex 7:23]
2. For max of date1 , hour1 should end at maximum of hour1 + additional_hour (2) [ ex 0:16]
3. For any other date1 , hour1 should be from 0:23

How do I achieve my result in data.table or data.frame format ? Any suggestions

```
   dt<-data.frame(date1=c('2020-01-04','2020-01-04','2020-01-04','2020-01-05','2020-01-05','2020-01-06','2020-01-06','2020-01-06'),
           hour1=c(7,8,10,11,9,10,11,14),visits=c(10:17),additional_hour=2)

   date1        hour1 visits  additional_hour
   2020-01-04     7     10       2
   2020-01-04     8     11       2 
   2020-01-04    10     12       2
   2020-01-05    11     13       2
   2020-01-05     9     14       2 
   2020-01-06    10     15       2
   2020-01-06    11     16       2
   2020-01-06    14     17       2
```

#### I tried this , but partly meets my requirement

```
dt1<-dt%>%group_by(date1)%>%complete(hour1=c(0:23),fill = list(visits = 0))
```

Comment: For item #2, is the maximum value of `hour1` calculated within the last date, or the maximum of `hour1` across dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) approach. This tries to simplify thing by making the `date1` and `hour1` fields into a `POSIXct` class. Then, we can simply use `seq.POSIXt` to help fill the missing times before joining back to the original data.

```r
library(data.table)
dt<-data.frame(date1=c('2020-01-04','2020-01-04','2020-01-04','2020-01-05','2020-01-05','2020-01-06','2020-01-06','2020-01-06'),
               hour1=c(7,8,10,11,9,10,11,14),visits=c(10:17),additional_hour=2)

setDT(dt)
dt[, grp := 1L ] 
dt[, date_hour := as.POSIXct(paste0(date1, sprintf("%02d", hour1)), format = "%Y-%m-%d%k")]

ans = dt[dt[, .(lookup = seq.POSIXt(min(date_hour),
                              max(date_hour) + as.ITime(sprintf('%0d:00', additional_hour[1L])),
                              by = 'hour')
          ),
      by = grp]
   , on = .(date_hour = lookup,
            grp = grp)]

setnafill(ans, fill = 0L, cols = 'visits')
ans
#>          date1 hour1 visits additional_hour   grp           date_hour
#>         <char> <num>  <int>           <num> <int>              <POSc>
#>  1: 2020-01-04     7     10               2     1 2020-01-04 07:00:00
#>  2: 2020-01-04     8     11               2     1 2020-01-04 08:00:00
#>  3:       <NA>    NA      0              NA     1 2020-01-04 09:00:00
#>  4: 2020-01-04    10     12               2     1 2020-01-04 10:00:00
#>  5:       <NA>    NA      0              NA     1 2020-01-04 11:00:00
#>  6:       <NA>    NA      0              NA     1 2020-01-04 12:00:00
#>  7:       <NA>    NA      0              NA     1 2020-01-04 13:00:00
#>  8:       <NA>    NA      0              NA     1 2020-01-04 14:00:00
#>  9:       <NA>    NA      0              NA     1 2020-01-04 15:00:00
#> 10:       <NA>    NA      0              NA     1 2020-01-04 16:00:00
#> 11:       <NA>    NA      0              NA     1 2020-01-04 17:00:00
#> 12:       <NA>    NA      0              NA     1 2020-01-04 18:00:00
#> 13:       <NA>    NA      0              NA     1 2020-01-04 19:00:00
#> 14:       <NA>    NA      0              NA     1 2020-01-04 20:00:00
#> 15:       <NA>    NA      0              NA     1 2020-01-04 21:00:00
#> 16:       <NA>    NA      0              NA     1 2020-01-04 22:00:00
#> 17:       <NA>    NA      0              NA     1 2020-01-04 23:00:00
#> 18:       <NA>    NA      0              NA     1 2020-01-05 00:00:00
#> 19:       <NA>    NA      0              NA     1 2020-01-05 01:00:00
#> 20:       <NA>    NA      0              NA     1 2020-01-05 02:00:00
#> 21:       <NA>    NA      0              NA     1 2020-01-05 03:00:00
#> 22:       <NA>    NA      0              NA     1 2020-01-05 04:00:00
#> 23:       <NA>    NA      0              NA     1 2020-01-05 05:00:00
#> 24:       <NA>    NA      0              NA     1 2020-01-05 06:00:00
#> 25:       <NA>    NA      0              NA     1 2020-01-05 07:00:00
#> 26:       <NA>    NA      0              NA     1 2020-01-05 08:00:00
#> 27: 2020-01-05     9     14               2     1 2020-01-05 09:00:00
#> 28:       <NA>    NA      0              NA     1 2020-01-05 10:00:00
#> 29: 2020-01-05    11     13               2     1 2020-01-05 11:00:00
#> 30:       <NA>    NA      0              NA     1 2020-01-05 12:00:00
#> 31:       <NA>    NA      0              NA     1 2020-01-05 13:00:00
#> 32:       <NA>    NA      0              NA     1 2020-01-05 14:00:00
#> 33:       <NA>    NA      0              NA     1 2020-01-05 15:00:00
#> 34:       <NA>    NA      0              NA     1 2020-01-05 16:00:00
#> 35:       <NA>    NA      0              NA     1 2020-01-05 17:00:00
#> 36:       <NA>    NA      0              NA     1 2020-01-05 18:00:00
#> 37:       <NA>    NA      0              NA     1 2020-01-05 19:00:00
#> 38:       <NA>    NA      0              NA     1 2020-01-05 20:00:00
#> 39:       <NA>    NA      0              NA     1 2020-01-05 21:00:00
#> 40:       <NA>    NA      0              NA     1 2020-01-05 22:00:00
#> 41:       <NA>    NA      0              NA     1 2020-01-05 23:00:00
#> 42:       <NA>    NA      0              NA     1 2020-01-06 00:00:00
#> 43:       <NA>    NA      0              NA     1 2020-01-06 01:00:00
#> 44:       <NA>    NA      0              NA     1 2020-01-06 02:00:00
#> 45:       <NA>    NA      0              NA     1 2020-01-06 03:00:00
#> 46:       <NA>    NA      0              NA     1 2020-01-06 04:00:00
#> 47:       <NA>    NA      0              NA     1 2020-01-06 05:00:00
#> 48:       <NA>    NA      0              NA     1 2020-01-06 06:00:00
#> 49:       <NA>    NA      0              NA     1 2020-01-06 07:00:00
#> 50:       <NA>    NA      0              NA     1 2020-01-06 08:00:00
#> 51:       <NA>    NA      0              NA     1 2020-01-06 09:00:00
#> 52: 2020-01-06    10     15               2     1 2020-01-06 10:00:00
#> 53: 2020-01-06    11     16               2     1 2020-01-06 11:00:00
#> 54:       <NA>    NA      0              NA     1 2020-01-06 12:00:00
#> 55:       <NA>    NA      0              NA     1 2020-01-06 13:00:00
#> 56: 2020-01-06    14     17               2     1 2020-01-06 14:00:00
#> 57:       <NA>    NA      0              NA     1 2020-01-06 15:00:00
#> 58:       <NA>    NA      0              NA     1 2020-01-06 16:00:00
#>          date1 hour1 visits additional_hour   grp           date_hour
```

Comment: I guess  I was not clear with question ,sorry for that ...you are defining min_hours = 7:23 & max_hours = 0:16 ......ideally min_hours and max_hours would be dynamic values . In my example I chose these values randomly                                                                     For one group ,min_hours might be 7:23 , for other it might be 13:23 ..I cannot manually change these values in my code , it has to be identified through script only rather than hard-coding these values in script ....Hope it makes sense !

Comment: Please edit your question with expected results. Related, for each group is ```additional_hour``` constant?

Comment: additional_hour would vary for each group , is not constant .Will update my question

Comment: Thanks a lot , only thing I want is to convert NAs to 0 for visits column

Comment: I am getting an error when I execute this                                                                 
 ans = dt[dt[, .(lookup = seq.POSIXt(min(date_hour),
                                     max(date_hour) + as.ITime(sprintf('%0d:00', additional_hour[1L])),
                                   by = 'hour')
 ),
 by = location_id]
 , on = .(date_hour = lookup,
         location_id = location_id)]                                                                                    
Error: 'to' must be a finite number.      here grp is equal to location_id

Comment: I would need more data. Are there any NA or Inf on additional hour? Are any hours greater than 23?

Comment: additional_hour values , in some cases , are more than 23 ....in that case it would change to next date1 For Example additional hour is 43 , then it should increase date1 by 1 full day and 19 hours  with another date1...

Comment: I made some changes to your script , like additional  hours were converted into seconds .  it worked finally                                                                                            
 ans = dt[dt[, .(lookup = seq.POSIXt(min(date_hour),max(date_hour) + additional_hour[1L],by = 'hour')),
by = location_id], on = .(date_hour = lookup,location_id = location_id)]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, the first date should include hours 7 through 23, and the last date hours 0 through 16. Using a combination of `tidyr` and `dplyr` packages, we can filter the data to eliminate the unwanted rows:

```
dt<-data.frame(date1=c('2020-01-04','2020-01-04','2020-01-04','2020-01-05','2020-01-05','2020-01-06','2020-01-06','2020-01-06'),
               hour1=c(7,8,10,11,9,10,11,14),visits=c(10:17),additional_hour=2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dt1<-dt %>% mutate(date1 = as.Date(date1,"%Y-%m-%d")) %>% 
     group_by(date1)%>%
     complete(hour1=c(0:23),fill = list(visits = 0)) %>%
     ungroup() %>% 
     filter(!(date1 == min(date1) & hour1 < 7) & !(date1 == max(date1) & hour1 > 16))
```

The `filter()` function as specified above eliminates rows where date1 is equal to its minimum value and `hour1` is less than 7, or where `date1` is equal to its maximum value and `hour1` is greater than 16. The first day will have 17 rows (hours 7 through 23), and the last day will have 17 rows (hours 0 through 16).

To confirm the results, we can count the number of rows by day.

```
# check results 
dt1 %>% group_by(date1) %>% summarise(count = n(),
                                      minHour = min(hour1),
                                      maxHour = max(hour1))
```

...and the output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  date1      count minHour maxHour
  <date>     <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 2020-01-04    17       7      23
2 2020-01-05    24       0      23
3 2020-01-06    17       0      16
```

### Making maximum hour a variable

Given comments to my answer, and the changes made to the question, here is an updated solution that saves the maximum value of `hour1` and `additional_hour` from the last day in the data frame, and uses them to `filter()` the last day's values.

```
# calculate max value of hour on max(date1) and additional_hour
dt %>% filter(date1 == max(date1)) %>% summarise(max_hour = max(hour1),
                                                 addl_hour = max(additional_hour)) -> parameters
# generate data & filter based on max_hour + additional_hour
dt1<-dt %>% mutate(date1 = as.Date(date1,"%Y-%m-%d")) %>%
     group_by(date1)%>%
     complete(hour1=c(0:23),fill = list(visits = 0)) %>%
     ungroup() %>% 
     filter(!(date1 == min(date1) & hour1 < 7) & 
                 !(date1 == max(date1) & hour1 > (parameters$max_hour + parameters$addl_hour)))

# check results 
dt1 %>% group_by(date1) %>% summarise(count = n(),
                                      minHour = min(hour1),
                                      maxHour = max(hour1))
```

...and the verification of the results.

```
> # check results 
> dt1 %>% group_by(date1) %>% summarise(count = n(),
+                                       minHour = min(hour1),
+                                       maxHour = max(hour1))
`summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  date1      count minHour maxHour
  <date>     <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 2020-01-04    17       7      23
2 2020-01-05    24       0      23
3 2020-01-06    17       0      16
```

Comment: This code has to be applied on a much bigger data set , so i cannot hard code these hour1 values , it has to be done programmatically ex hour1 > 16 , hour1 < 7

Comment: @YogeshKumar - I don't understand your comment. As written, my answer does use the `hour1` values programmatically in the `filter()` function. There appears to be some context in your mind that you did not write into the question, and therefore I can't address it without further explanation from you. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I meant you are using hour1 > 16 , hour1 < 7 while filtering ...that number would depend on different groups of data ...these hour1 values can be anything not necessarily as given in example ( hour1 16/7) , I want to use any  value based on data , so script should automatically find the minimum/maximum of hour1 for  min(date1)/max(date1)... Hope you get my point ! Also , you are not using addditional_hour value in your script ..n manually adding 14+2 = 16 while filtering

Comment: @YogeshKumar - sorry, I'm more confused now than I was after your prior comment. I'm getting lost in the indirect references in your comments. Please update your question to make it more clear, and I can update my answer to account for the additional details. This means you'll need to add additional data to illustrate the variability that must be accounted for in the filter, and explain concretely how it should be used.

Comment: @YogeshKumar - Does the updated version of my answer address your comments?